# Unable to HTTP POST using python raw socket

Tags: python

I am trying to do a http post on a url using a python raw socket.But I am unable to do so, while http get requests are working fine.
The problem is when I try post.

My code

```
import socket

HOST = 'www.example.com'

PORT = 80

DATA = "POST /example/email.php HTTP/1.1\r\n" # send headers
"HOST: example.com\r\n"
"Accept: */\r\n*"
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
"Referer: http://example.com/example/\r\n"
"action=subscribeme&email=laaarr@gmail.com\r\n"  #actual post payload data



def tcp_client():
    client = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(( HOST, PORT ))
    client.send(DATA)
    response = client.recv(4096)
    print response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tcp_client()
```

There is no error/reply from the server side(bad request or anything else) but it seems to be not working. Everything else is correct, because I checked them on POSTMAN and by curl.

Comment: There's got to be some kind of a response. 200/404/500 or a timeout.

Comment: print your data to see what you get

Comment: @DeepSpace there is no error. I set socket timeout to 5sec. Plus, same http packet is working fine with curl and postman

Comment: @Marko...I am already printing the response. see in the third last line of code.There is no response from server side.

Comment: Have you tried adding extra blank lines `"\r\n"` (not sure if 1 or 2) before the request body? That is how it is normally done.

Comment: @janbrohl I really like that understatement. *how it is normally done.* for *how it is mandated by the HTTP standard* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try it with

```
DATA = ("POST /example/email.php HTTP/1.1\r\n" # send headers
"HOST: example.com\r\n"
"Accept: *\r\n"
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
"Referer: http://example.com/example/\r\n"
"\r\n" # blank line seperating headers from body 
"action=subscribeme&email=laaarr@gmail.com\r\n")  #actual post payload data
```

and you should get an answer.

Using

```
import socket

HOST = 'www.example.com'

PORT = 80

DATA = ("POST /example/email.php HTTP/1.1\r\n" # send headers
"HOST: example.com\r\n"
"Accept: *\r\n"
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
"Referer: http://example.com/example/\r\n"
"\r\n" # blank line seperating headers from body 
"action=subscribeme&email=laaarr@gmail.com\r\n")  #actual post payload data 


def tcp_client():
    client = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(( HOST, PORT ))
    client.send(DATA)
    response = client.recv(4096)
    print response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tcp_client()
```

I get

```
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required    
Content-Type: text/html    
Content-Length: 357    
Connection: close    
Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2016 11:23:16 GMT    
Server: ECSF (ewr/1443)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>411 - Length Required</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>411 - Length Required</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

which obviously is an error but totally a response.

With

```
DATA = ("POST /example/email.php HTTP/1.1\r\n" # send headers
"HOST: example.com\r\n"
"Accept: *\r\n"
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
"Content-Length: 41\r\n" #fixes error 411
"Referer: http://example.com/example/\r\n"
"\r\n" # blank line seperating headers from body 
"action=subscribeme&email=laaarr@gmail.com")  #actual post payload data
```

I get a normal `404 Not Found`.

Comment: .,,I tried with it but no success.still no response.

Comment: i tested it an uincluded my results in answer